# Sorting a paragraph alphabetical using javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

So I need to input a paragraph and sort it alphabetical and strip all commas, periods from it. so if the input is:

```
var nonSortedArray = ['hi', 'yo', 'whatup', 'bye', 'lol'];
var sortedArray = nonSortedArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  else if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
});
console.log(sortedArray);
```

I thought I would be using something like this, but Im not sure how to display the paragraph because I can't have a comma after every word either.

Comment: sidenote: `Array#sort` doesn't return a sorted array, it sorts in place and returns `this`; so in some way it does return a sorted array, but `nonSortedArray` is also sorted now and `sortedArray === nonSortedArray`.

Comment: Thank you for asking your question clearly, with your expected output, and the code you’ve already tried.

Comment: Why did you delete the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match only word characters, filter with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique words and sort them.

```js
var string = 'Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds. There are blue, pink, and purple swirls, spinning and twisting, like clouds of balloons caught in a blender.',
    words = Array
        .from(new Set(string.match(/\w+/g)))
        .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .join(' | ');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = words;
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `replace()`ing `,` and `.` and then use split by `space` before `sorting` and `joining` with pipe `|` character.

```js
let str = 'Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds. There are blue, pink, and purple swirls, spinning and twisting, like clouds of balloons caught in a blender.';
const ar = [... new Set(str.replace(/[,.]/g,'').split(' ').sort((a, b)=> a.localeCompare(b)))].join('|');
console.log(ar);
```